# postUrl runs only once

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am calling postUrl in action-javascript that is referenced from Bixby sample on https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/tree/master/http-api-calls

```
var http = require('http')
var console = require('console')
var config = require('config')

module.exports.function = function adjustVolume (volume) {
  var o = { };
  var options = {
    passAsJson: true,
    returnHeaders: true,
    format: 'json'
  };

  var response = http.postUrl(config.get('remote.url') + '/api/gvm/control/volume/' + volume, o, options);

  return "ok";
}
```

BTW, postUrl to my remote service runs only one time, all later postUrl does not come into my remote service. Then I need to restart Bixby developer studio again to get postUrl to my remote service.

With getUrl, there is no symptom above.
Did I miss any constraint about using postUrl ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Bixby platform caches the response from your remote server, and keeps re-serving it to your capsule code. I found that the solution is to set the `cacheTime` in the options to 0, and this makes the Bixby platform call your remote server again every time. Substitute the following for your options above (adding `cacheTime` on its own line):

```
  var options = {
    passAsJson: true,
    returnHeaders: true,
    format: 'json',
    cacheTime: 0       // <--- this is the new line to add
  };
```

I found this out when I wrote a [tutorial capsule using remote storage](https://github.com/vboughner/bixby-capsule-with-aws). I was using `http.postUrl` to access my remote server and had to update the options for the `postUrl` call at [this place in the code](https://github.com/vboughner/bixby-capsule-with-aws/blob/cfb54eb67c3c8d46b440748be58d0ebdc3b052bb/capsule/code/rest.js#L55), or it wouldn't call the remote server more than once. The solution was setting the `cacheTime` to 0, as I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Van! Always helpful!